# C++ iterate or split UTF-8 string into array of symbols?

Tags: c++, arrays, utf-8, split

Searching for a platform- and 3rd-party-library- independent way of iterating UTF-8 string or splitting it into array of UTF-8 symbols.

Please post a code snippet.

**Solved:**
[C++ iterate or split UTF-8 string into array of symbols?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2852895/c-iterate-or-split-utf-8-string-into-array-of-symbols#2856241)

Comment: C++ doesn't have any standard facilities for dealing with UTF-8 encoding. So, it's either use a separate library, or write your own. Writing your own is possible but there are zillions of details.

Comment: Yes, that is the reason I'm asking the question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Solved using tiny platform-independent [UTF8 CPP](https://github.com/nemtrif/utfcpp) library:

```
    char* str = (char*)text.c_str();    // utf-8 string
    char* str_i = str;                  // string iterator
    char* end = str+strlen(str)+1;      // end iterator

    do
    {
        uint32_t code = utf8::next(str_i, end); // get 32 bit code of a utf-8 symbol
        if (code == 0)
            continue;

        unsigned char[5] symbol = {0};
        utf8::append(code, symbol); // copy code to symbol

        // ... do something with symbol
    }
    while ( str_i < end );
```

Comment: On some language a word contains 2 or more symbols like '哈哈' in Chinese, should one use `vector<uint32_t>` to store a word? If so, comparing words seems require iterating the vector/array and it seems quite slow...

Answer (score 31):

If I understand correctly, it sounds like you want to find the start of each UTF-8 character.  If so, then it would be fairly straightforward to parse them (interpreting them is a different matter).  But the definition of how many octets are involved is well-defined by the [RFC](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3629.txt):

```
Char. number range  |        UTF-8 octet sequence
   (hexadecimal)    |              (binary)
--------------------+---------------------------------------------
0000 0000-0000 007F | 0xxxxxxx
0000 0080-0000 07FF | 110xxxxx 10xxxxxx
0000 0800-0000 FFFF | 1110xxxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx
0001 0000-0010 FFFF | 11110xxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx
```

For example, if `lb` has the first octet of a UTF-8 character, I think the following would determine the number of octets involved.

```
unsigned char lb;

if (( lb & 0x80 ) == 0 )          // lead bit is zero, must be a single ascii
   printf( "1 octet\n" );
else if (( lb & 0xE0 ) == 0xC0 )  // 110x xxxx
   printf( "2 octets\n" );
else if (( lb & 0xF0 ) == 0xE0 ) // 1110 xxxx
   printf( "3 octets\n" );
else if (( lb & 0xF8 ) == 0xF0 ) // 1111 0xxx
   printf( "4 octets\n" );
else
   printf( "Unrecognized lead byte (%02x)\n", lb );
```

Ultimately, though, you are going to be much better off using an existing library as suggested in another post.  The above code might categorize the characters according to octets, but it doesn't help "do" anything with them once that is finished.

Comment: Beautiful answer! This is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

[UTF8 CPP](https://github.com/nemtrif/utfcpp) is exactly what you want

Comment: I've already found this library by myself. I needed a code, but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Try [ICU Library](http://site.icu-project.org/).

Comment: "3rd-party-library- independent way"

Comment: +1 ICU is a cross-platform library released under a permissive open source license. If the OP wishes to avoid dependency on a 3rd party library, the source code of ICU is freely available but contains over 1e+06 lines of code.

Comment: It is open source. You could try to use source of string iterator from it, not all 1e+06 lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

Off the cuff:

```
// Return length of s converted. On success return should equal s.length().
// On error return points to the character where decoding failed.
// Remember to check the success flag since decoding errors could occur at
// the end of the string
int convert(std::vector<int>& u, const std::string& s, bool& success) {
    success = false;
    int cp = 0;
    int runlen = 0;
    for (std::string::const_iterator it = s.begin(), end = s.end(); it != end; ++it) {
        int ch = static_cast<unsigned char>(*it);
        if (runlen > 0) {
            if ((ch & 0xc0 != 0x80) || cp == 0) return it-s.begin();
            cp = (cp << 6) + (ch & 0x3f);
            if (--runlen == 0) {
                u.push_back(cp);
                cp = 0;
            }
        }
        else if (cp == 0) {
            if (ch < 0x80)      { u.push_back(ch); }
            else if (ch > 0xf8) return it-s.begin();
            else if (ch > 0xf0) { cp = ch & 7; runlen = 3; }
            else if (ch > 0xe0) { cp = ch & 0xf; runlen = 2; }
            else if (ch > 0xc0) { cp = ch & 0x1f; runlen = 1; }
            else return it-s.begin(); // stop on error
        }
        else return it-s.begin();
    }
    success = runlen == 0; // verify we are between codepoints
    return s.length();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Does endianess matter for this function?

Comment: "if (*it < 0x80) { u.push_back(*it); }" => "comparison is always true due to limited range of data type"

Comment: invalid conversion from `const char* const' to `char*'

Comment: Ok, I fixed the bugs. UTF8 is strictly byte level so endianness cannot matter.

Comment: What? "Endianness is the ordering of individually addressable sub-units (words, bytes, or even bits)" (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) Multi-byte encoding depends on endianess.

Comment: I'll say it again. UTF8 is a byte level encoding. That means you read each byte sequentially. It doesn't matter what order the bits are transmitted in between IP ports or from main memory to the microprocessor's registers. When those bits are put back together they are interpreted the same way on all processors (19 == 19). Endianness is not an issue.